# In Chrome, how can I set a cookie with a max-age of less than 213 days?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

**Update:**
The solution was to restart my computer. I think the issue occurred because I changed my Windows date & time settings many times recently in order to do some testing. I think that must have thrown Chrome for a loop. Once I restarted, everything worked as expected.

When I try to set a cookie using JavaScript in Chrome with a max-age of less than 213 days, no cookie is set. My function seems to work fine in FireFox.

I'm not sure if I have an error in my setCookie function (below), or if Chrome is limiting me.

https://codepen.io/edtalmadge/pen/pxdqvK

```js
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
  document.cookie =
    name + "=" + value + "; Max-Age=" + days * 86400 + "; path=/";
  console.log(document.cookie);
}

setCookie("foo", "123", 212); // no cookie set

setCookie("bar", "456", 213); // cookie is set
```

Comment: for whatever its worth, I ran that exact code and it worked for me (both cookies are set).

Comment: @lemieuxster, thanks for running the code. Even when I run the code in the pen (linked below), the first cookie is not set. Does the pen work for you too?

Answer (score 1):

Your code did work for me on Chrome, but `max-age` has had [quirks in the past](https://mrcoles.com/blog/cookies-max-age-vs-expires/). Perhaps, give `expires` a shot instead. You can also try lowercasing `Max-Age` to `max-age` as shown in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

```js
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

setCookie("foo", "123", 212);
setCookie("bar", "456", 213);
```

Comment: Thanks Raphael. The solution was to restart my computer. I think the issue occurred because I changed my Windows date & time settings many times recently in order to do some testing. I think that must have thrown Chrome for a loop. Once I restarted, everything worked as expected.